# What is the main difference between using React-Redux Hooks and React-Redux Connect()?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am about to start a project with React-Redux. For the APIs references there are Hooks and connect(). Since, Hooks are the alternate of connect APIs. What is the difference of using hooks or connect to my React-Redux project.

Answer (score 18):

> What is the difference between using hooks and `connect` to my React-Redux project

There are two major differences:

- Scope
  `connect` can be used with both React class components and function components whereas hooks can be used with function components only.
- Performance vs simplicity
  Using hooks is simpler. The simplicity comes at a price: you have less performance tweaks at your disposal in comparison with `connect`. Which is more complex: you call it passing in configuration options (few or many) and get back the 'configured flavor' of `connect`. This flavor is the HOC that you call passing in your component to get it back wrapped.
  One of the main configuration options is the already mentioned `mapStateToProps` function. You don't have to use it but it most cases you will. There are 4 other functions that exist solely to give you various opportunities to improve the performance of the component you are going to wrap around using `connect`. The functions are called:
  `areStatesEqual`
  `areStatePropsEqual`
  `areOwnPropsEqual`
  `areMergedPropsEqual`
  All 4 are optional. You can pass in as the `connect` configuration options either none or some or all of them and tweak the performance. It's worth noting that even if you pass in none, then the default implementations of those functions (which are effectively performance helpers) will apply and as a result, you will get the wrapped component that is more optimised performance-wise than its hooks-using counterpart.

Comment: Very true, I find my hooked components a tad slower than the HOC ones. I wonder what React is doing to address this in the Hook infrastructure or does the fault lie more with React-Redux? And can performance tweak be otherwise exposed via the useSelector function?

Comment: @Eniola React authors/maintainers would know better, I got a feeling they accept that now hooks offer less optimisation choices. The good thing about `connect()` is it accepts both function and class components so one can always use Redux with a function component without hooks.

Comment: Current industry standard, everyone is using hooks and not much connect(). If connect() comes with such performance promises, then why useSelector is more in use? Is React team introduced any concept which counters connect() performance advantages? I am starting a new project, and answer to this could really help me take right decision.

Answer (score 13):

`connect` is a `High Order Component` whose job is to provide a way to connect Redux's store to your `components`. `useSelector` and `useDispatch` are the equivalent `hooks`. Just another technique to do the same thing.

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        const { fetchApi, arg } = this.props
        fetchApi(arg)
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>({
    fetchApi : arg => dispatch(fetchApi(arg))
})
const mapStateToProps = state =>({
    arg : state.arg
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

Now the equivalent using `hooks`

```
const Component = () =>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const arg = useSelector(state => state.arg)

    useEffect(() =>{
       dispatch(fetchApi(arg))
    },[dispatch, arg])
}
```

Both do exactly the same thing, it's only a different approach to connect `redux` to `components` internal `state`. Both consume Redux's context to expose `dispatch` and `state` inside a given `component`

Comment: How will you gauge the perf differences?

Comment: Very concise and clear example, way better than the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

React-Redux internally uses [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to connect components to the store.

The `connect()` function wraps your component into another component that connects to the store context and forwards the selected state to your component as props.

If you called...

```
const YourConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)`
```

...you can imagine the wrapper to roughly look like this:

```
const YourConnectedComponent = props => (
    <StoreContext.Consumer>
        {state => <YourComponent {...props} {...mapStateToProps(state, props)} />}
    </StoreContext.Consumer>
);
```

`mapStateToProps` in this case would be the function you provided to `connect()`.
This is very simplified and it doesn't actually look exactly like this for various performance reasons but it is suitable to demonstrate the general concept.

The `useSelector` hook also consumes the store context but without creating a component in between for that. It directly returns the selected state for the component to use it. It internally uses `useContext` which is "the hooks way" to consume a context.

`useDispatch` just exposes `dispatch()` to your component for it to dispatch actions with it.

Technically the outcome is more or less the same whether you are using hooks or `connect()`.

Answer (score 4):

Hooks enable you to access `dispatch` and redux-state directly with out connecting the  component using `connect` and hooks can be used only in functional components

`Connect` enables us to link our component(Class or functional ) with `redux-store`,

You can refer to `react-redux` hooks documentation from [this](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks) link.

It has given different hooks like

`useSelector` using which we can access redux store
`useDispatch` returns `dispatch` function with which we can dispatch redux actions

Sample usage of redux hooks for a component will be(Can use this only in functional Components)

```
functions Test() {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const count = useSelector(state => state.counter)
// If you want to dispatch a redux action using hooks then
// Assume a redux action called increaseCounter

return (
<>
<p>{count}</p>
<button onClick={() => {dispatch(increaseCounter(count + 1))}}>
ClickMe!
</button></>)
}
```

If you want to achieve the same using connect then(you can use this in Class or functional components)

```
function Test() {
  return (
    <>
      <p>{this.props.count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => {this.props.increaseCounter(this.props.count+1)}}>Click Me!</button>
    </>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    count: state.counter
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators({ increaseCounter }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Test)
```