# React-Redux: Do I have to use connect() and map state/dispatch on all my components from a single component tree? Is there a way to do it only once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So basically I have an app with a single component tree. `App` as a parent and then it goes down from there. Initially, all of the states are obviously centralized from the parent component `App`, as it is normally, and then the state is passed per component via props. We all know this is a hassle as the component tree gets bigger and bigger.

I'm studying React-Redux and just curious if I always have to use `connect()` and then each create a `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` for each and all my components including the subcomponents? Is there a one-off way to do this? Isn't it possible for my many components to just access the entire store without mapping each state/dispatch to props one-by-one, which I find repetitive and time-consuming?

I came from a Vue-Vuex background (although my Vuex experience is limited) and React-Redux is just a whole different ball wax, if not quite a lot more complicated IMO.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think there is any problem creating mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps for each component as each component might need different actions and state so it makes sense to create them for each component. Like say you have two reducers Employee and Project, and for their components you will take states and actions which are only needed in that component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Redux you don't have to connect all the components to its store. You only connect the components that really need it. For example, if a connected component has children then it might be simpler not to connect the childeren to Redux but rather let the connected parent drive the updates for its children. Grandkids can be coonected but not their immediate children and so forth. There can be many approaches and every component can still have its own private state in addition to Redux store.

Currently `React.FunctionComponent`s are in fashion and you can use [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook instead of `connect` though you will have [less possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027300/what-is-the-main-difference-between-using-react-redux-hooks-and-react-redux-conn/58029394#58029394) to fine-tune for performance with the hook.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Redux FAQ entry on "Should I connect all my components, or just one?"](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#should-i-only-connect-my-top-component-or-can-i-connect-multiple-components-in-my-tree):

> Early Redux documentation advised that you should only have a few connected components near the top of your component tree. However, time and experience has shown that such a component architecture generally requires a few components to know too much about the data requirements of all their descendants, and forces them to pass down a confusing number of props.
>
> > Emphasizing “one container component at the top” in Redux examples was a mistake. Don't take this as a maxim. Try to keep your presentation components separate. Create container components by connecting them when it's convenient. Whenever you feel like you're duplicating code in parent components to provide data for same kinds of children, time to extract a container. Generally as soon as you feel a parent knows too much about “personal” data or actions of its children, time to extract a container.
>
> In fact, benchmarks have shown that more connected components generally leads to better performance than fewer connected components.
>
> In general, try to find a balance between understandable data flow and areas of responsibility with your components.

Answer (score 1):

Your state in `redux` store doesn't change, but in order to use it, you should use `connect` and connect to your store.
If you don't want to use connect,
 you can simply pass your states to a child component by props like
 `<mycomponent data={this.state.data} />`
And use your data in your child component
If these ways not satisfying you can read about the context system, but it's parent to the child again, but you can pass data from parent to grandchild without using child

[You can read about it here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Hope this helps you.