# how to render updated state in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to update state and render the updated value in my component but unable to achieve it.

<--Here is my action -->

```
export const fetchProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await fakeApi.get("/products");
  console.log(res.data);
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_PRODUCTS,
    payload: res.data,
  });
};
```

<--Here is the reducer -->

```
const initialState = {
  products: [],
};

    export default (state = initialState, action) => {
      const { type, payload } = action;
      switch (type) {
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS:
          return { ...state, products: payload };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

<--Here is the component -->

```
const Products = ({ products, fetchProducts }) => {
 const [productsList,setProductsList]=useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
    console.log(products);
    setProductsList({productsList:products})
  }, []);

  return <ProductList products={productsList} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: state.products,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchProducts })(Products);
```

<-- This is the first time I am using redux. I don't know where I am going wrong.All i am getting is undefined in the state. -->

Comment: Which state is "undefined"? Redux state? The local component `productList` state? Presumably if your reducer is named `products` then I think your state would be `state.products.products`. `fetchProducts` is an `async` action creator, so `products` will still be the initial state when the component mounted. Storing passed props (i.e. `products`) into local component state is a react anti-pattern, just pass `products` directly to `ProductList` component.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (add a codesandbox) [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As all this happens asynchronously, it will be undefined for a moment there, then it should render again and then have a value. Unless your app crashes before that second update, seen that a lot. So make sure it doesn't crash when you get `undefined` for a moment there.
Also, as with the other answer. Go for the hooks. See the official tutorials I linked in a comment under the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are using react hooks for a function-based component, using [useSelector()](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) hook instead of mapStateToProps might be easier in this specific scenario to get data from redux store, as i can't see what you've named your reducer in the root reducer, i'm assuming it's named productReducer, try this in your component:

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'
```

...

```
let products = useSelector(state=>state.productReducer.Products)
```

Comment: You can use redux hooks **and** `mapStateToProps`, sometimes it even recommended, refer to redux docs. (And its `import { useSelector } ...`)

Comment: You can actually use the `connect` Higher Order Component to decorate ***any*** react component, which includes functional components.

Comment: @DennisVash I'm very sure that we don't recommend beginners with function components to use `connect`. The official recommendation is pretty simple: if you can use hooks, go for hooks. They're a lot easier to reason about for beginners.
See the [style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/) and the [official tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index).

Comment: I said "sometimes it even recommended", I didn't recommend using connect only. For reasons why it does, try searching connect vs hooks (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027300/what-is-the-main-difference-between-using-react-redux-hooks-and-react-redux-conn#:~:text=useDispatch%20just%20exposes%20dispatch(),using%20hooks%20or%20connect()%20.&text=connect%20can%20be%20used%20with,used%20with%20function%20components%20only.)

Comment: Of course I can't speak for everyone on the internet, but I can speak for the redux team:
The official recommendation is "[Prefer using the React-Redux hooks API (useSelector and useDispatch) as the default way to interact with a Redux store from your React components.](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api)"
There might be a point where connect makes sense, but these cases are very rare and usually you will never reach them. Sometimes you just *need* connect, but apart from those very specific cases, we don't recommend using it instead of hooks.

Comment: It's ok, I still recommend using the `connect` HOC as it 100% decouples internal component implementation from data sources, but this is a design choice. @MohabKhaled The `useSelector` import is still incorrect, but thank you for your edit to not imply that `connect` wouldn't work with a functional component.

Comment: @DrewReese, edited..thank you, and also for giving a reason why you would recommend connect with hooks